# ssh through port forwarding lag raspberry pi

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi, lag

I have set up raspberry-pi on my home LAN and want to access it remotely.
I have set up ssh daemon and port forwarding and i can login into raspbpi and do terminal work.

The problem is, that sometimes, some commands got "stuck" and react after several minutes delay.

For example:

When I run 'ls' i see half of the files and second half appears after many minutes.

Running 'cat file.txt' executes instantly, but 'vim file.txt' usually opens blank file and wait for text to load for several minutes.

Why these lags occur and what can I try to experience lag free interaction?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Why does these lags occur and how to solve them? Waiting several minutes for content of file totally destroys workflow.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is not meant to be a machine to work from all the time and it is a very low powered processor.  That being said, have you adjusted the video/system ram split?  Have you overclocked it?  How are you sure that it's the Pi's fault and not your connection (i.e. does this happen when you are home using it too, or only from a distance?)?